# Alternate path in Orchard

Tags: c#, orchardcms

I've created my own class which adds alternates to the relevant collection:

```
ShapeMetadata.Alternates.Add("DansForm");
```

This works fine, but only when `DansForm` is in the `Views` root.

I want to keep all the `DansForm` alternates in a directory.

**How can I reference a path?**

---

**What I've tried:**

```
ShapeMetadata.Alternates.Add("Forms/DansForm");
ShapeMetadata.Alternates.Add("/Forms.DansForm");
ShapeMetadata.Alternates.Add("Forms.DansForm");
ShapeMetadata.Alternates.Add("Forms\\DansForm");
ShapeMetadata.Alternates.Add("Forms__DansForm");
ShapeMetadata.Alternates.Add("Forms_DansForm");
```

Doesn't find any of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant organise shape templates into directories. Orchard has a hardcoded list of directories it searches for shape templates:

```
public IEnumerable<string> SubPaths() {
    return new[] { "Views", "Views/Items", "Views/Parts", "Views/Fields" };
}
```

I guess this is for performance reasons. I suppose you could write an additional implementation of IShapeTemplateHarvester to find shapes in your own folders, but seems like overkill just to make it a little more organised. I think you'll just have to suffer the mess of views. Sorry!